# Extend EF DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am not sure if what i am asking is the way to go. I have a DB first model. I want to add certain common methods to it, like updating a specific field of a specific table.

I know i could do this by creating a class with the appropriate methods like:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void UpdateFieldAOfTableA(int newValue)
    {
        using(DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            //Update Code
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a way of extending the DBContext, so i could just call:

```
DBContext.UpdateFieldAOfTableA(newValue);
```

I tried creating a partial class and adding an extension such as:

```
public partial class DBContext
{
    public static void UpdateFieldAOfTableA(this DBContext db,int newValue)
    {
        //Update Code here
    }
}
```

but this obviously didn't work as i can extent only non-generic static classes and this is not static.

Do you think what i am trying to do is wrong? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `DBContext` is already declared as a partial class, you don't need to use an extension method.  This should work:

```
public partial class DBContext
{
    public void UpdateFieldAOfTableA(int newValue)
    {
        //Update Code here
    }
}
```

You should now be able to call `DBContext.UpdateFieldAOfTableA(newValue);`.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was quite confused as to how to refer to SaveChanges. this.SaveChanges wouldn't work. I only had to call plain SaveChanges.

Comment: nintendojunkie / @GiannisParaskevopoulos, I'm hoping one of you can help me... Saw this answer and tried it and getting errors - Posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182012/entity-framework-5-extending-dbcontext-class - Any thoughts??